# factorization of $ A = BB^T $

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I have a positive semi definite real matrix $ A $. I know I can find a real matrix B such that $ A = BB^T $. It is clear that I can add a zero column to $B$ and $ A = BB^T $ still holds for my new matrix $B$. But can I find a different **square** matrix $B$ such that $  A = BB^T $ or is it that this factorization is unique if I require that $B$ is square ?

Thanks!

Comment: The factorisation is not unique. Think about orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Obviously you can change $B$ to $B'=BP$ for any orthogonal matrix $P$ and have $B'B'^T=BB^T$.